# How to count specific words in a list from a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how I can count the number of unique words that I have in a list from a specific data frame.
For example, let's say I have a list = `['John','Bob,'Hannah']`
Next, I have a data frame with a column called sentences

```
df = 

       ['sentences']
 
0 Bob went to the shop

1 John visited Hannah

2 Hannah ate a burger
```

I want the output to be:

```
John 1

Bob 1

Hannah 2
```

How can I count the unique names in any given sentence in any row in a dataset?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate, please see the existing 1300+ Q&A on [\[pandas\] string count](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+string+count). Also, do you care about handling the case of multiple occurreces? (*"John visited Hannah when Hannah was in hospital"*)

Comment: My bad, I didn't know how to navigate this website I just created an account. I guess I'm only looking for unique occurrences as the other users have posted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.contains` and call the `sum` to get the number of occurances of a word in the given column, just iterate over the list for all the substrings and do the same for each word, store the result as dictionary.

```py
list1 = ['John','Bob','Hannah']
output = {}
for word in list1:
    output[word] = df['sentences'].str.contains(word).sum()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
{'John': 1, 'Bob': 1, 'Hannah': 2}
```

You can even use it in a dictionary comprehension:

```py
>>> {word: df['sentences'].str.contains(word).sum() for word in list1}
{'John': 1, 'Bob': 1, 'Hannah': 2}
```

**PS:** If a word/substring is present multiple time in the same row of the given column, the above method will count those multiple occurrences as 1, if you want to get multiple counts in that case, you can implement the same logic for each cell value

Answer (score 3):

You also may use `str.split`, `explode`, and `value_counts`

```
l = ['John', 'Bob', 'Hannah']
df.sentences.str.split().explode().value_counts()[l]

Out[239]:
John      1
Bob       1
Hannah    2
Name: sentences, dtype: int64
```

However, I think `dict comprehension` is faster.

Comment: almost same here ~ :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
list1 = ['John','Bob','Hannah']
df.Col1.str.findall('|'.join(list1)).explode().value_counts()
Hannah    2
Bob       1
John      1
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
```